# Why are my emails going to spam?

Tags: email, phishing, gmail, email-spoofing, postfix

I have been trying to learn about phishing emails. I have read up quite a bit on it. I setup a domain somthing.tk (free domain), hosted a website on a VPS (Digital Ocean). Set up my own mail transfer agent (Postfix).

Now I have set up:

1. DKIM
2. DMARC
3. SPF

All pass in GMail when I send the mail, but still the mails send by me are flagged as spam by GMail spam filter. What am I doing wrong?

Also I am using GNUMail to send emails via this command:

`echo "anything" | mail -s "subject" anything@gmail.com`

Comment: When Gmail puts a message in Spam, there's a giant banner at the top that says "Why is this message in spam?" followed by the answer. What does that say for your emails?

Comment: Why is this message in Spam? It's similar to messages that were detected by our spam filters.

Comment: then it is not the transport layer that it is detecting but the content

Comment: should i not use gnu mail?should i use it but increase my content?

Comment: I bet using `.tk` has something to do with this. The same setup with `.icu` seemed to work fine. [Not anymore!](https://blocked.icu/) TLD reputation matters.

Comment: To see if your mail server has a problem (that you may have overlooked) that would cause other mail servers to think it's a spammer, try sending a message from your mail server to check-auth@verifier.port25.com. This service will do a bunch of checks, and you'll get a report back with ton of information, such weather or not your mail server's DNS is setup correctly, whether your mail server's IP is on any black lists, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, **.tk** is one of the TLDs that are notoriously associated with certain threat actors and are used by malware to establish C2 channels (malware home-calling).

[SNORT](https://www.snort.org/) and [Suricata](https://suricata-ids.org/) (two most widely-used opensource IDS/IPS solutions) even have detection rules written for **.tk**, **.pw** and **.ru** URLs, it would generate an alert for the SOC analysts every time a hit is recorded against them in the network.

I'd suggest using a purchased domain name to get past the email filters.  GL!

---

**BONUS:** You might want to check your URL/domain names at https://www.urlvoid.com to see if they're marked malicious or suspicious by security vendors/spam databases.